# Node.js Windows SSL Cert REST

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, node-request

I'm trying to call a REST Url which is SSL protected.
I'd like to use the certificate from the cert store but, I'm not sure how to propagate the cert to the call through the request.

I did look at the NPM Package windows-certs but, was not sure how to use it.

Comment: why do you need certs to call rest url ? are you using mutual ssl ?

Comment: The endpoint is protected with SSL. I need to present a certificate to the URL. No we are not using mutual SSL

Comment: i didn't get that. If your endpoint is protected with SSL, then it would present you its certificate, not you. If you need to provide your certificate, then its mutual ssl.

Comment: I take it back, it is mutual SSL.

Comment: cool, where is certificate stored ? You can use `request` module https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#tlsssl-protocol

Comment: The Certificates are in the windows cert Store

Comment: I haven't tried it before, but first, tries to export cert and key for the cert, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/import-export-certificates-private-keys#1TC=windows-7 and then use request module to access the endpoint. I could not find any module that can read windows cert store.

Comment: The certificates in our store cannot be exported. But I did get our network team to give me an exported PEM file

based on which I got this error

 Failed to send the message because{"code":"SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN"}